# Can't retrieve data using ExecuteReader() when grouping queries

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, oledb

I need to retrieve the information stored in a database of some thousand items. If I go one by one by this way it takes a large amount of time (tac is a 8-character string):

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DataBase\IMEIDB.accdb";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT TAC, Name, Model, Year, Manufacturer, LTE FROM Terminales WHERE TAC = @tac";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tac", tac);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ulong tac = Convert.ToUInt64(reader.GetString(0));
            if (this.DiccionarioTerminales.ContainsKey(tac))
            {
                DiccionarioTerminales[tac].inDB = true;
                DiccionarioTerminales[tac].Name = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                DiccionarioTerminales[tac].Manufacturer = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                DiccionarioTerminales[tac].Model = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                DiccionarioTerminales[tac].Year = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                DiccionarioTerminales[tac].LTE = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
            }
        }
        command.Dispose();
    }
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

It works well (I know I must use `ExecuteNonQuery()` if it's only one record, but this example is only a test), but if I try to group the tac 10 by 10 (now tac is a string like `'xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx'...`) with the next changes in my code...

```
OleDbDataReader reader;
command.CommandText = "SELECT TAC, Name, Model, Year, Manufacturer, LTE FROM Terminales WHERE TAC IN (@tac)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tac", tac);
```

It doesn't enter in the `while` loop and I don't know why...

Is there something that am I missing or maybe I need to use another method to retrieve those data?

**EDIT**: Change the format due to the [Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-g%C3%B6n%C3%BCl) answer

Comment: I think you mean `ExecuteScalar` not `ExecuteNonQuery` :)

Comment: What kind of data is tac? Integer? String?

Comment: What is the value being passed in `tac` parameter? By the way - how is it supposed to group anything? It is only used in `where` condition of your query.

Comment: In the first example is a 8-character string, in the second example is a group of 10 8-character string separated by commas into a single string.

Comment: The easiest is to split on clientside and loop all tacs.

Comment: @TimSchmelter if I go tac by tac works, but it takes a long time because there're about 6K different tacs. I grouped it tying to reduce the amount of time spended.

Answer (score 5):

Because when you use this string in `IN` clause, it will seems like;

```
IN (xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx)
```

but the *right* syntax should be

```
IN ('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx')
```

That's why it doesn't work. One solution might be, you can split your string with `,`, format them with using single quotes and join them `,` again.

```
var str = "xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx";
var result = string.Join(",", str.Split(',').Select(s => string.Format("'{0}'", s)));
```

`result` will be `'xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx'` and you can use it in your `IN` clause like;

```
...TAC IN (@tac)
```

and

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tac", result);
```

Also don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Related: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/337704/447156)

Comment: @FernandoGallegoFernández Only `Add(String, Object)` overload is obsolete. You can use _other_ overloads such as `Add(String, SqlDbType, Int32)`.

Comment: If I ise the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tac", result);` the content of the result string is `"'35582006','35152207','01383700','35291306','86794902','35590206','35925406','35300107','35595206','35663305'"` (as an example) but still don't enter in the while loop

Comment: @FernandoGallegoFernández Is it query returns any data in your database manager? Are you %100 sure your `TAC` column has one of _those_ values?

Comment: Yes, because if I go one by one as I told in the first example it works. Even if I use Access with the next query: `SELECT TAC, Name, Model, Year, Manufacturer, LTE
FROM Terminales
WHERE TAC IN ('35582006','35152207','01383700','35291306','86794902','35590206','35925406','‌​35300107','35595206','35663305');` it returns me 2 diferent terminals...

Comment: In fact, if I use the thext code in my program `command.CommandText = "SELECT TAC,Name,Model, Year, LTE FROM Terminales WHERE TAC IN ("
                            + result 
                            +")";` it works! But this is not well constructed due to SQL-Injection...